# Location and name of FTP Log files

Tags: ftp, logs

A vendor is transfering files via FTP to our location via FTP and claims that they did send us the files. Where can I find the FTP log files and what are they called?

Comment: Your admin should be able to tell you. The answer depends on how your admin set this up and also depends on whether he set up or disabled logging. Lets start with: what program is used to do ftp?

Comment: We currently have very limited knowldege surrounding this environment. So please bare with me......How can I determine what program could be used for this? I pretty sure we are just using whatever gets installed by default for the OS.

Comment: If you have superuser do (aka 'sudo') you can type `sudo lsof -i | grep ftp` edit your question and add the results.

Comment: @LourensPrinsloo there is no ftp installed by default. Here is a limited list of possible ones: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html

Comment: The command resulted in nothing.

Comment: Then either you don't have FTP server installed, or it's running in another port, you may need to use `sudo lsof -i` instead. BTW, when answering someone comments use `@name` so they get notified..

Comment: /var/log/vsftpd.log

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your FTP server, but most log files are in `/var/log`. Most servers just log errors and warnings by default, so I'm not entirely sure you can find the log of file transfers, since they tend to take too much space.

You can use also `locate` to find them in case you have an idea of what are they called, like `ftp.log`.

Comment: or maybe it is called `xferlog` ;)